# Video recording interference

Tags: interference, electronics

I'm currently working on an Android App that records while driving in a car. Similar to the popular Dashcams. While developing this App I saw a lot of ugly glitches on my videos. I used a Nexus 5 for the recording.

This glitches that appear like waves on the video only appear inside my car when I either start the car or rev it a bit. They also appear when I turn up the volume of the sound. The Car is a Ford Focus RS 2010. In other cars I could not reproduce this. This only happened in this exact car.

I put up a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rC_gTBnev8k&feature=youtu.be) on youtube which demonstrates this. This was recorded with the standard Android Camera App just to make sure that this is not caused by an implementation Error.

Now I'm really interested in what can cause such a thing. Currently I would assume this is some sort of electrical interference that comes from the car and messes the recording up. Is there a name for this? Anything I can read up?

Comment: Sorry, isn't is just the vibrations - combined with some struggling software to stabilize the image? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I think its not vibrations. Because I used the same holder in different cars and mine is the only one that causes this to videos. Its correct that I have some vibrations while driving but they look completely different on the video. Also I can reproduce this effect with the motor off and only changing the volume of my music.

Comment: @Qmechanic I was torn between putting it here or to Electrical Engineering. I think moderators are able to move questions right?

Comment: @Playerwtf : Yes. Do you want to migrate it?

Comment: Yes if you can do that that would be great.

Answer (score -2):

The device is either extremely hot ioniZing the air right in front of the lens or the air inside the car is ionized.

Comment: The device was definitely a bit hot because of the recording but I would assume that the full recording would have this waves then. Currently it really only happens when I do something like turning the car on or reving or increasing the volume. I think it must be something electrical. Just to be sure I also made sure that the Android device was not connected to the power supply of the car. The result was the same.